# Python PyQt - MVC Pattern - Model Class To Work With View and Object

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt

I am trying to learn pyQt programming in a MVC pattern(which in QT there is not controller, so really just Model/View). I have try1.py which is the graphics I made from QT designer. In that, I have 2 line edit boxes- Username and Password. Then I have test.py which is the actual python script.

1) Since the text lines widgets are nested in the global Ui_Form....how would I assign the model to them? typically I would use something like `widgetView = setModel(model)` but I don't know how to do this with  `self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)`. Since I am trying to use MVC I assume this needs to be outside of Ui_Form class?

2) Would I have 2 different models- 1 for username widget and 1 for password?

3) How would I get the TextLineModel to update the fields in the X object instance and the View get updated as well?

This is the try1.py QT Editor already compiled by pyuic.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'try1.ui'
#
# Created: Mon May 27 04:00:05 2013
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

    class Ui_Form(object):
        def setupUi(self, Form):
            Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
            Form.resize(640, 480)
            self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 71, 16))
            self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
            self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
            self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 61, 16))
            self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
            self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
            self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 30, 231, 20))
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
            self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
            self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 60, 231, 20))
            self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
            self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
            self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 361, 81))
            self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayoutWidget"))
            self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.verticalLayout_2.setMargin(0)
            self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))

            self.retranslateUi(Form)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        def retranslateUi(self, Form):
            Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
            self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "UserName:", None))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Password:", None))
```

This is the script test.py script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from untitled import Ui_Form
from collections import OrderedDict

class GetInfo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.info = OrderedDict([('userName', None),
                     ('passWord', ' ')]

    def login_name(self):
        name = raw_input("Enter Login Name: ")
        self.login_info["login_name"] = name

    def password(self):
        name = raw_input("Enter Password: ")
        self.login_info["password"] = name


class TextLineModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
        def __init__(self, text, parent = none):
             QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
             self._text = text

         def data(self, index, roll):
                if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                    value = self._text
                    return value



class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = GetInfo()
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have to link up your model and your widgets using [QDataWidgetmapper](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QDataWidgetMapper.html).

2)No, you should have a single model for a single class of data. In your case it should be `QAbstractTablemodel`.

3)You can call `QDataWidgetmapper.revert()` to update widgets with data from the model. The model is either updated automatically after user is done with widget editing, or by manually calling `QDataWidgetmapper.submit()` (see `QDataWidgetmapper.submitPolicy`)

Comment: shouldn't make much difference. docs [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdatawidgetmapper.html)

Comment: It's actually does not matter in this case :) The Qt model\view framework is a part of Qt. It does not matter what kind of bindings you use to access it. But to ease your mind here [goes](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdatawidgetmapper.html)

Comment: I see QDataWidgetMapper.setModel (self, QAbstractItemModel model) so I was aware of the setModel() method already, which brings me back to question #1? That is...without using a utility to do it.

Comment: Place initialization where it is supposed to be - MyForm.__init__(). Create instances of the model and widget mapper, and make them members of your MyForm instance. Then call self.mapper.setModel(self.model) And wait a couple of mins while I come up with a working exaple.

Comment: Thanks, that is a excellent learning tool. I still do not see where a instance of User() is created and where it's values get updated by the model.

Comment: Well, your task is to create model and populate it with data. The moment you will populate the model is up to you - you can do that at the moment your form is created, for instance. Or you can place a refresh button on the form. Or wait for some signal or event. It all depends on your app. In the simplest case you should put it into MyForm.__init__(). In my example it happens at lines 52-58. Model created AND populated with data, model linked with QDataWidgetMapper - mapper is told to fetch a first row (an essential step, BTW)

Comment: Ah, forgot to add - the model is not a data store, it is just a strongly formalized interface between YOUR CUSTOM data structure (in this case - a list of User instances) and widgets\views. When widgets are edited they call mapper and it calls model.setData(UserDataFromAWidget). The model then puts the data into your data storage, as YOU described in model.setData(). If you didn't redefine setData(), nothing will happen. No magic there - you have to tell the model explicitly how to read and write data to your data storage - by redefining data() and setData().