# PyQt model of complex class

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a Python class with attributes that aren't as simple as the very limited set of PyQt Model/View examples I can find:

```
class my_data_class(object):
    def __init__(self,name='default',index=0):
        self.name = name
        self.index = index
        # self.data is a variable length list of dictonaries
        self.data = [{'dataset_name':'table1', 'x':[1.0,2.0,3.0], 'y':[4.0,5.0,6.0]},
                     {'dataset_name':'table2', 'x':[5.0,2.0,3.1], 'y':[1.1,1.0,1.0]}]
```

I'd like to make a viewing/editing form for this class instance that looks like this:

[image: gui editor/viewer for the above class definition]

I read the Qt C++ model/view tutorial [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/modelview.html) and the combo widget mapper C++ tutorial [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-itemviews-combowidgetmapper-example.html), but I'm not seeing anything for anything more complex than a table. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772374/python-pyqt-mvc-pattern-model-class-to-work-with-view-and-object) also mentions using the `QDataWidgetMapper`, but I have no idea how to use that for a structure like this class instance.

Should I be using multiple models to represent the single class instance? One for each view or something? That seems messy. Should I define a custom widget to define essentially a collection of simpler widgets? Not sure how that would work either. Maybe subclass `QModelIndex` somehow to allow finding data within a general class and not be limited to `row()` and `column()`?

**I can't be the first one who wanted a PyQt editor/viewer for populating a complex class. What's the best way to go about this?**

Comment: you can consider using a QTreeview. It is more complex than a table. Every table (in your example) will be a node in your treeView.

Answer (score 0):

QAbstractItemModel http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html is the most generic Qt model that you can subclass to define your own model : a list, a table or a tree model but also more complex data structures.

QStyledItemDelegate could help if you need to customize the rendering/editing of items in the view.

QDataWidgetMapper could be another choice indeed if you need a binding between widgets like QLabel, QSpinBox ... and a model.